# Windows phone 7 performance issues when using GeoCoordinateWatcher?

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7

Can I use GeoCoordinateWatcher in Application_Launching to check that the phone location service is enabled or disabled? Does this affect performance?

Regards,

Panache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't!

Let the app launch and then decide.
You need your app to function even if the location service is disabled.

There is no time guarantee in confirming the location service is running so if you wait you may go over your allowed start up time.

Or are you just asking how to use a GeoCoordinateWatcher?

**Edit:**
If you want to only display this once, then just keep track of if you've displayed the prompt/message.

Also be aware that due to settings being changed while your app is tombstoned just performing the check on application launch does not guarantee that it will always be correct.

e.g.

- location service disabled when app
  started
- App displays prompt
- User presses start (app tombstoned)
- uses changes settings to enable location service
- user uses back button to reactivate app
- app restarted (If doesn't RE-check if service enabled then would be wrong)

Comment: Hi Matt Lacey, thanks for the reply. I want to check the if(e.Status == GeoPositionStatus.Disabled)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Application can't access your current location. Check your location services in phone settings."); } only once. so i made this in Application_Launching. If i made this check in my MainPage loaded it will show me every time when MainPage will load. So will you suggest me some way to make it once in my app? And i know how to use GeoCoordinateWatcher. Regards, panache.

Comment: Ya you are right. I have to maintain the track then it will be working the way we want. Thanks a lot Matt Lacey.  Regards, panache